# Undistort distortion parameters

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm trying to undistort an image with OpenCV (through OpenCVSharp's wrapper) and i'm having trouble figuring out the correct format for the matrices, i'm improting them through the CvFileStorage as used in the undistort sample however i'm getting really unexpected results.

From another software i use i get the following data (which should be right as that software undistorts the iamge just fine with those parameters)

```
    <sensor id="0" label="RP_OV5647 (3.5976 mm)" type="frame">
      <resolution width="2592" height="1944"/>
      <property name="focal_length" value="3.5975999999999999e+000"/>
      <property name="fixed" value="false"/>
      <calibration type="frame" class="adjusted">
        <resolution width="2592" height="1944"/>
        <fx>2.5667779156627239e+003</fx>
        <fy>2.5654169232963172e+003</fy>
        <cx>1.2933905910821311e+003</cx>
        <cy>9.6694162774618212e+002</cy>
        <skew>2.9824815660771562e+000</skew>
        <k1>9.1041365324307497e-002</k1>
        <k2>-4.0485507081497402e-001</k2>
        <k3>3.3943759073230600e-001</k3>
        <p1>3.4409596859645629e-004</p1>
        <p2>-3.9472652058529605e-005</p2>
      </calibration>
    </sensor>
```

i'm using the following code to undistort the images, the intrinsic matrix is fine (gives the expected result when applying no distortion) however the distortion matrix is giving me issues, from what i understand of the expected layout (didn't find any samples but that's what i gather from the OpenCV source) a 4X1 matrix with k1k2p1p2 should work so i have this in my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
   <intrinsic type_id="opencv-matrix">
   <rows>3</rows>
   <cols>3</cols>
   <dt>f</dt>
   <data>
      1293.3905910821311 0. 966.94162774618212 0. 2566.7779156627239 2565.4169232963172 0. 0. 1.
   </data>
 </intrinsic>
 <distortion type_id="opencv-matrix">
   <rows>1</rows>
   <cols>5</cols>
   <dt>f</dt>
   <data>
  0.091041365324307497 -0.40485507081497402 0.00034409596859645629 -0.000039472652058529605 0.33943759073230600
   </data>
 </distortion>
```

Code :

```
            using (IplImage srcImg = new IplImage(img.Path, LoadMode.Color))
            using (IplImage dstImg = srcImg.Clone())
            {
                CvMat intrinsic, distortion;
                using (CvFileStorage fs = new CvFileStorage("camera.xml", null, FileStorageMode.Read))
                {
                    CvFileNode param = fs.GetFileNodeByName(null, "intrinsic");
                    intrinsic = fs.Read<CvMat>(param);
                    param = fs.GetFileNodeByName(null, "distortion");
                    distortion = fs.Read<CvMat>(param);
                }
                Cv.Undistort2(srcImg, dstImg, intrinsic, distortion);
                dstImg.SaveImage(new System.IO.FileInfo(img.Path).Name);
            }
```

However i'm getting completly distorted images (Whirlpool) , do i have the matrix order wrong? is there any code sample (i couldn't find any) with a matrix constructed from named parameters (all i found was a sample using a sample file with a matrix in it and no documentation on the component orders)?

Comment: Print the values of `intrinsic` and `distortion` to make sure you read them ok.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger OpenCV is reading them directly from it's own format of xml file so i don't think there's an issue there, at what step in code would you like for me to read them and display them? I'll update the OP with that information but i'm not sure where to do it

Comment: are your intrinsics in the right order? it looks like you're providing them mirrored and transposed or sth.? Try `2566.7779156627239 2.9824815660771562 1293.3905910821311 0 2565.4169232963172 966.94162774618212 0 0 1` please

Comment: @Micka Aaaand that was it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure about the `skew` parameter, but this code gives me completely different results than your provided image (but it isn't equal to your "correct" corrected image either)

```
int main()
{
    // camera resolution
    cv::Mat input= cv::imread("../inputData/distorted1.jpg");


    cv::Mat distCoeff;
    distCoeff = cv::Mat::zeros(8,1,CV_64FC1);

    // indices: k1, k2, p1, p2, k3, k4, k5, k6 
    // your coefficients here!
    double k1 = 9.1041365324307497e-002;
    double k2 = -4.0485507081497402e-001;
    double p1 = 3.4409596859645629e-004;
    double p2 = -3.9472652058529605e-005;
    double k3 = 3.3943759073230600e-001;
    double k4 = 0;
    double k5 = 0;
    double k6 = 0;

    distCoeff.at<double>(0,0) = k1;
    distCoeff.at<double>(1,0) = k2;
    distCoeff.at<double>(2,0) = p1;
    distCoeff.at<double>(3,0) = p2;
    distCoeff.at<double>(4,0) = k3;
    distCoeff.at<double>(5,0) = k4;
    distCoeff.at<double>(6,0) = k5;
    distCoeff.at<double>(7,0) = k6;


    // camera intrinsics
    cv::Mat cam1;
    cam1 = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    cam1.at<float>(0,0) = 2.5667779156627239e+003;
    //cam1.at<float>(0,1) = 0;
    cam1.at<float>(0,1) = 2.9824815660771562e+000; // skew?
    cam1.at<float>(0,2) = 1.2933905910821311e+003;

    cam1.at<float>(1,0) = 0;
    cam1.at<float>(1,1) = 2.5654169232963172e+003;
    cam1.at<float>(1,2) = 9.6694162774618212e+002;

    // direct undistort:
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::undistort(input, output, cam1,distCoeff);


    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("distCorr-direct", output);

    cv::waitKey(-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug view of the distortion matrix : {CvMat(Rows=8, Cols=1)
0,0910413653243075 
-0,404855070814974 
0,000344095968596456 
-3,94726520585296E-05 
0,339437590732306 
0 
0 
0 
}

Comment: And the intrinsic one : {CvMat(Rows=3, Cols=3)
1293,390625 0 966,941650390625 
0 2566,77783203125 2565,4169921875 
0 0 1 
}

Comment: so your intrinsics differ... you provide `cx, 0, cy, 0, fx, fy, 0, 0, 1` but it should be `fx, skew, cx, 0, fy, cy, 0, 0, 1` see my comment above

Comment: marking this as an answer and will award both you and hannes a Bounty in 2 days when i can, that was really helpful!

Comment: I'll upvote Hannes too, because the missing `k3` was one major part.

Comment: could you remove the picture from the answer? i meant for the link to be temporary and i'd rather not have that image directly visible and indexable on the internet

Answer (score 2):

Since the calibration you get is for five parameters `k1, k2, k3, p1, p2` then you should use all of them for the undistortion.
Currently you are skipping `k3`.

Try adding the value of `k3` to your configuration file to make the `distortion` parameter have dimensions `1x5`.
Note that the order should be `k1, k2, p1, p2, k3`.

Comment: That fixed the Whirlpool effect but i still think i've got Something else wrong as it's way way unlike the expected output, i'm going to update the OP with 3 photos (undistorted, distorted, and my wrong undistorted version) i think it will be easier that way as it's a visual problem

Comment: Make sure to post the intrinsics as well, because then we can actually test it.

Comment: I added the full sample files, uploading the pictures in a minute

Comment: Added the sample pictures too : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9b2yig17ggnztuw/AAAUveWYj2HETnONiRqglMfHa?dl=0